# Как связать GlassFish сервер и мобильное приложение?

Tags: java, android, glassfish, java-ee

Уважаемые знатоки, подскажите, есть работающее приложение на GlassFish сервере (сайт), и я хочу разработать мобильное приложение под Android, для работы с этим сервисом. Как правильно это реализовать, какие технологии использовать?

Comment: Я думаю, что связать их можно так же, как и любое другое веб приложение. Серверная часть на GlassFish, а клиентская часть - на Андроиде. Клиент обращается посредством веб запросов, как обычно (Get, Post). Можно воспользоваться [HttpClient][1] на Андроиде. Вот [туториал][2]. Извини, на русском нормальных туториалов на эту тему не нашел. Но этот весьма хороший и мне помог.


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html
  [2]: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNetworking/article.html

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Я еще не уверен, но, по-моему, это должно быть что-то вроде RESTful веб-службы. Мне нужно получать от сервера уже готовые данные.

Comment: Я так представляю себе схему: 
1) сервис, доступный по адресу mydomain.com/service
2) Из андроида, делаю запрос,  запрашиваю данные
3) Принимаю JSON
4) Пишу его в кэш (SQLite)
5) Получаю данные из базы и работаю с ними
6) С заданной периодичностью обновляю данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фтыкай [сюда](http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123) - простой пример обращения к RESTful веб-сервису из Android'а.

Ну если вы, конечно, уверены, что на стороне сервера наружу высунут именно RESTful сервис.

Если более глубже смотреть, то ответ сервера надо писать в БД (типа кэша), над которым надстраивать контент провайдер, который аппе выдает курсор. Соответственно далее вся работа ведется с этим `Cursor`ом. Далее надо рисовать сервис, который мониторит БД и сервис и время от времени синхронизирует кэш.

Как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо, вот это уже теплее! Так я и есть разработчик сайта, и думаю, что мне нужно "высунуть" наружу для связи с Андроидом. А обмениваться, скорее всего, буду xml-файлами.

Comment: @b1ack_ange1 наружу надо высовывать JSON, XML уже не считается православным средством. Посмотрите на [простейший работающий веб сервис](http://time.jsontest.com), который возвращает json строку с текущим временем и датой

Comment: Ок, странно, почему XML стал в опале, ну раз нынче JSON  моде и на нем пообщаемся. Спасибо за ссылки.

Comment: Да потому что XML это непрерывная попаболь, парсить его удовольствие ниже среднего, он неэкономичен - ну и т.д. JSON действительно удобен - напрямую транслируется в Java объект. Посмотри в сторону [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) - оч. удобно

Comment: Так я же сам буду формировать эти XML, marshalling/unmarshalling и никаких проблем, тоже все будет транслироваться напрямую в java-объект, который я заранее опишу. Разве что с файлами с большой вложенностью трудно действительно работать. Я вроде использовал раньше JSONSimple.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше юзай tomcat + spring. 
Spring boot actuator позволяет вообще не ставить tomcat - он будет сам разворачиваться в любом месте, где ты запустишь приложение, а после завершения сворачиваться.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/

Comment: Спасибо, можно поизучать. Я думаю он и с GlassFIsh сервером должен подружиться.